# How to get the value of an object property by using a variable

Tags: javascript

Here is code I have

```
var person ={
  name: 'John'
};
var v = 'name';

console.log(person.name); // John
console.log(person.v);    // undefined
console.log(v in person); // true
```

As you can see in the code, person.v returns undefined.

I'd like to know if it is possible to print 'John' using variable v.

Comment: The `[ ]` operator. `person[v]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this:

```
 var person ={
      name: 'John'
    };
    var v = 'name';

    console.log(person.name); // John
    console.log(person[v]);    //john
```

Answer (score 0):

`person[v]` should work in this situation